# Can I create a Comparator object from a lambda expression without explicit variable?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I am not yet familiar with lambda expression in Java.

Can

```
//create a comparator object using a Lambda expression
Comparator<Double> compareDouble = (d1, d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2);

//Sort the Collection in this case 'testList' in reverse order
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder(compareDouble));
```

be written without explicitly create a variable `compareDouble`?

I tried the following, but why does it not work?

```
//Sort the Collection in this case 'testList' in reverse order
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Double> ((d1, d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2))));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/

Comment: This can be simplified into testList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(Double::compareTo));

Answer (score 2):

First, your immediate error: You forgot to place parentheses around your casting type.  Try:

```
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder( (Comparator<Double>) ((d1, d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2))));
```

<sub>Edit: The above error was when the question didn't have `new` so it looked like a cast.</sub>

Also, Java's type inference will work without explicitly casting your lambda expression to the necessary functional type.  Try:

```
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder( (d1, d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2) ));
```

When the comparison operation already exists as in this case, you can make it even simpler with a method reference:

```
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder(Double::compare));
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to type in `new` to invoke constructor, and didn't intend to use casting. Why doesn't `new`  work?

Comment: When you're using `new`, you're attempting to create a new instance of something directly, but `Comparator` is an interface.  The lambda expression itself is sufficient code.

Comment: @rgettman `Double` already implements `Comparable`, a simple `Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder())` will do

Answer (score 2):

`Double` already implements `Comparable`, so you can use the zero-arg [`reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--) overload:

```
testList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Or you can reverse your custom comparator:

```
testList.sort((d1, d2) -> d2.compareTo(d1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I’d go with something like:

```
Collections.sort(testList, Comparator.comparingDouble(Type::getDoubleValue).reversed());
```

Where `Type` is the name of your class and `getDoubleValue` is the `double` value being used as the sort key.

Another shorter alternative.

```
testList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Type::getDoubleValue).reversed());
```

**edit**

I think I’ve misinterpreted your current problem. Nevertheless, altering your current solution to:

```
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder((e, a) -> e.compareTo(a)));
```

Would suffice.

It’s just a matter of taking the behavior you’ve assigned to the variable `compareDouble` and directly pass it into the `reverseOrder` method.